# Selecting DISTINCT records on subset of columns with MAX in another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have been looking at other T-SQL questions including DISTINCT and MAX here on the site for a couple hours now, but cannot find anything that quite matches my need. Here is a desription of my dataset and query objectives. Any guidance is much appreciated.

**Dataset** 
Dataset is a list of customers, customer sites, dates and values from the last billing cycle, with the following columns. It is possible for a single customer to have multiple sites:

Customer, Site, Date, Counter, CounterValue, CollectorNode

**Query Requirements**
For the given billing cycle, I would like to select the following

- DISTINCT (Customer and Site)
- MAX(CounterValue) for this billing cycle for each DISTINCT Customer and Site
- While still returning all the fields for that record from the table (CollectorNode, Date, Counter)

My challenge here is my inability to return all the columns while selecting the DISTINCT columns and MAX for each. My many varied attempts return multiple records for each customer/site combination.

Answer (score 8):

### Using a self JOIN:

```
SELECT ds.customer,
       ds.site,
       ds.counter, 
       ds.countervalue,
       ds.collectornode
  FROM DATASET ds
  JOIN (SELECT t.customer,
               t.site,
               MAX(t.countervalue) AS max_countervalue
          FROM DATASET t
      GROUP BY t.customer, t.site) x ON x.customer = ds.customer
                                    AND x.site = ds.site
                                    AND x.max_countervalue = ds.countervalue
```

### Using a CTE & ROW_NUMBER (SQL Server 2005+):

```
WITH example AS (
   SELECT ds.customer,
          ds.site,
          ds.counter, 
          ds.countervalue,
          ds.collectornode,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ds.customer, ds.site
                                ORDER BY ds.countervalue DESC) AS rank
     FROM DATASET ds)
SELECT e.customer,
       e.site,
       e.counter, 
       e.countervalue,
       e.collectornode
  FROM example e
 WHERE e.rank = 1
```

Comment: How would I incorporate a WHERE clause into the 'Self JOIN' example. While I want to report on the current billing month, we have several months of data and need to filter the record set to just those of our target date range (start and end date) of our choosing.

Comment: @PJZ: In the self join, the safest means is to specify the WHERE criteria to both the `ds` and within the brackets that house the derived table query for `x`.  Applying the WHERE to only one risks the other not having the same values.

Comment: I see what you mean. Going to work with this a bit Monday and see if I can work out the query with your advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use a subquery to do the grouping and join the result back to the original table, like this:

```
SELECT g.Customer, g.Site, c.Date, c.Counter, g.MaxCounterValue, c.CollectorNode
FROM Customers c
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT Customer, Site, MAX(CounterValue) MaxCounterValue
FROM Customers
GROUP BY Customer, Site
) g
ON g.Customer = c.Customer
AND g.Site = g.Site
```